# Why can't modern weapons kill Godzilla?

Tags: godzilla, godzilla-2014, monsterverse

I ask this question because of a review of the newest Godzilla trailer done by Beyond the Trailer on YouTube. She points out in the video that it is hard to suspend the belief that we have no way (so it seems) of hurting Godzilla even though he is flesh and bone.

I am just wondering if there is some explanation given or implied as to why we can't fire some sort of armor piercing weapons at him or a MOAB/Nuke/JDAM type of bomb. It may be too early to speculate given that this is the very first official main trailer and if that is the case then I can understand not having an answer.

Is this simply a case of "we have to accept it because its a movie" or is there some explanation why modern weaponry cannot hurt the beast.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about the new Godzilla, the original, the 2000 version, some other version? The new one would likely fall under "speculation" since nobody knows exactly what his new weaknesses may be.

Comment: @phantom42 The newest Godzilla

Comment: Yeah, any answers here would be pure speculation at this point. [This page](http://godzilla.wikia.com/wiki/Godzilla) goes over Godzilla's historical weaknesses and reasons for his durability.

Comment: @phantom42 Ahh ok! we'll have to wait and see! but thank you for the link it may give me an idea of how this new Godzilla will survive.

Comment: You may want to wait a while before marking an answer as "accepted". For all you know, someone may come along with a canon quote about the new film...

Comment: Then it would be a very short movie.

Comment: @Oldcat - watching them fire shot after shot into Godzilla's writhing corpse for 90 minutes would still be more enjoyable than the Green Lantern movie.

Comment: How about shots into the Green Lantern's writhing body?

Comment: The new Godzilla movie is just a lead in to the Pacific Rim sequel where humanity will build a Mecha-Godzilla to defeat him.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's very difficult to extrapolate on the basis of a single trailer but historically modern weaponry has been relatively useless against Godzilla (all canons) due to his size, armoured skin, skill at evading missiles and artillery and his ability to use his breath to avert impacts.

Nukes tend to be off the table because of the urban locations he attacks (or defends) and heavy weaponry is a bit useless when he goes underwater or into hiding.

He is, of course especially vulnerable to being choked to death with trees but, heck every superhero has to have an Achilles heel...

[image]

Comment: And here I thought the answer was that Godzilla is the psychological manifestation of Japan's guilty conscience over World War 2, and as such, no physical weapon can hurt it. :)

Comment: The point about nukes being off the table is a good one, and its a theme expanded upon directly by [Neon Genesis Evangelion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neon_Genesis_Evangelion), where the city is rebuilt to submerge underground in the event of an attack by such a creature. Godzilla has come to destroy, dropping a nuke probably just gives him the afternoon off.

Comment: Well, now after the film.. we know that Nukes weren't off the table.. neither they managed to kill Godzilla ( or more precisely, i think they named it like that in film, it's father/mother) when they were used against it in 1950s.. aand with that i totally go with 'we have to accept that' thingy, especially when I see JDAM/GBUs blowing on back of the 'enemy' monster during it's walk through Las Vegas without any harm, and yet it get's pierced& killed at the end with steel bar from wrecked skyscraper..

Comment: Holy crap, I didn't expect that fallout at the bottom of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Godzilla appears to be more than 300 meters tall, 450 meters long, and 90,000 tons (most accepted measurements) so I assume his skin is so thick that even an armour piercing bulit should get about a foot past his outer most layer of scales

He also lives at the bottom of the ocean, where the pressure alone is greater than what most weapons can dish out.

Also, he once took a meteor (about the same size as he is) straight to the chest and he never even flinched. Forget nukes.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that *mere exposure* to high levels of radioactivity only *make him stronger*; as such, nukes would not only fail to kill Godzilla, but when one takes into account that a nuke has a stronger blast force than any other (recently used) bomb/missile, this means that a direct hit would also make him *fighting mad*. Calling such an action counter-productive would be a *massive* understatement.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually said on the wiki and in one of the movies that Godzilla is made up of G-cells which give him his power, and the ability to heal incredibly fast.

Comment: Hi there, welcome! :) could you add the quote and its source? Maybe a YouTube clip or something? This would help in making your answer more consistent.

Comment: See the "regeneration" section of [this article](https://screenrant.com/godzilla-powers-abilities-versions-explained/) for a source. But this plot point was only stated in the 1984-1995 [Heisei era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godzilla_(franchise)#Heisei_era_(1984–1995)) as far as I know, so it may not be part of the 2014 movie's canon.

Comment: It is my view that kaiju exist according to alternate physical laws, other than the laws that the rest of the Earth lives by. This explains how such huge animals would even be able to exist, instead of collapsing under their own weight.

Answer (score 0):

I think if remember Godzilla can adsorb nuclear power so any weapon containing that would be futile , he would soak it up and become more powerful . He is the folly of man Godzilla .

Comment: Nukes are only one possible modern weapon; there are also MOABs, and in theory it's possible to build a shaped charge/EFP large enough to penetrate any thickness of armour.  You could also improve this by pointing to evidence that Godzilla could withstand not simply nuclear radiation, but also ground-zero temperatures and blast overpressure.  As it is this is far too brief for a proper answer and seems more like a comment.

Comment: Sure thats the smart way , but of course we wouldn't learn are lesson and attack him with what we created him by . You have to factor in movie logic . Your way wouldn't be used until he caused billions in damage and thousands  killed .